# ACF - Add/update featured image (for videos) by field

Tags: post-thumbnails, videos

I'm trying to add thumbnails to my videos by a ACF field. Therefore I'm looking for some PHP which add/update the featured image on videos (at the Attachment Details screen). I tested this code from the ACF forum but it doesn't seem to work

```
// Set the first sock image uploaded as the featured image
function acf_set_featured_image( $value, $post_id, $field  ){

if($value != ''){
  delete_post_thumbnail( $post_id);
  //Add the value which is the image ID to the _thumbnail_id meta data for the current post
  add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $value);
}

return $value;
}

// acf/update_value/name={$field_name} - filter for a specific field based on it's name
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=video_thumbnail', 'acf_set_featured_image', 10, 3);

//field name: video_thumbnail
```

**Update:**
I'm such an idiot... - I've edit the wrong function.php, therefore the code above is fine.   :|

Note: I added this line to edit existing images.

```
delete_post_thumbnail( $post_id);
```

Comment: where you found this filter example `acf/update_value/name=video_thumbnail`?

Comment: In this discussion: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/set-image-as-featured-image/

Comment: have you tried to update the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will happen when you update the key `name`.

```
File: wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/fields/_functions.php
193:        foreach( array('key', 'name', 'type') as $key )
194:        {
195:            // run filters
196:            $value = apply_filters('acf/update_value/' . $key . '=' . $field[ $key ], $value, $post_id, $field); // new filter
197:        }
```

Try to: print $value, $post_id, $field to understand what you have...
Likely you have some wrong label...

```
function acf_set_featured_image( $value, $post_id, $field  ){
// print $value, $post_id, $field to understand what you have...
print_r(...);

wp_die();

if($value != ''){
    //Add the value which is the image ID to the _thumbnail_id meta data for the current post
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $value);
}

return $value;
}

// acf/update_value/name={$field_name} - filter for a specific field based on it's name
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=video_thumbnail', 'acf_set_featured_image', 10, 3);
```